# windows 7 hangs at shutdown and reboot

Tags: windows-7

I recently installed Windows 7 and it was fine for a few weeks however now it hangs when I try to shut it down so I have to hold the power button to turn it off.

This issue started a few days after i had installed AVG and I didn't install anything else after that.

I tried some hot-fixes that were on Microsoft's website however none of them had made any difference. I also tried using system restore to take it back before I had installed avg however that didn't make any difference so I'm not sure what to do now.

Comment: what doesn logs say `start->run->eventvwr` section `Windows Logs -> System`. I  assume there will be atleast something to unveil mystery

Answer (score 1):

Restore the system to an earlier restore point:

1. Open the Control Panel and in the search box, type "restore" then select the link that says "Create a Restore Point."
2. Click the button that says "System Restore."
3. Click "Next>."
4. Click the point you wish to restore to. To see more options check the box that says "Show more restore points."
5. Click "Next>."
6. Confirm your restore point and click "Finish."

   Instructions can also be found here:
   [How to Use System Restore in Windows 7, 8, and 10](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-windows-vista-system-restore/)

Comment: While this may be useful advice, the question is very old and your answer lacks necessary information or explanation and so is not particularly helpful in its current form.

Comment: @music2myear I have fixed my explanation. Please remove your downvote.

Comment: This is now a link-only answer. I recommend you read the Help section to understand the few basic rules and the reasons behind them. The basic gist relevant to your answer is that we want the answers here to be self-sufficient, with explanation and solutions included here. Links are good and should be used when the information comes from somewhere else, but should never be necessary to understand or apply the solution, so that if the link changes or goes bad, the answer is still relevant and useful.

Comment: @music2myear I have further elaborated. Please remove your downvote.

Comment: I was not the one who downvoted.

Comment: And the downvote wasn't mine either, so here you go to balance it ...

Answer (score 0):

1.perhaps it is because there is not driver installed and my advice to install intel driver rapid storage technology.

if the number 1 still fails please try the solution below

2.If the computer problem as it often happens, restart the computer by using the restart button, to go back into Windows. While Windows is active, try to perform the following steps:

A. Select Disable Error Reporting setting. One way that Windows hangs when system errors occur is to select the setting disable error reporting system. The trick is to run the Control Panel [Start> CorrtrolPanel] and then double-click on the icon [System] tab and click the [Advanced> Error Reporting]. Select the option [Disable error reporting] to disable error reporting action.

B. To do modifications to the hung-up by editing the Windows registry using Regedit. Use the [Start> Run ...] and type [Regedit]. Select the HKEY_CURRENT_USER \ Control Panel \ Desktop. Right-click the [HungAppTimeout] and select [Modify]. HungApp time to modify, change the value data box, then click OK and reboot to your Windows to run the changes have been made​​.

C. Another way is return the BIOS to its default setting, there may be a setting that interferes with the process

Comment: there is nothing to do with intel rapid driver.

Answer (score -1):

Also, you can try to restore the system files from the boot option

***Try looking through this article for detail walkthrough***

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/run-system-file-checker-safe-mode-boot-time

Comment: Can you add more information to your post please? If you could explain why this fixes the issue and expand on how to do what you suggest would make a better answer.

Comment: changed the answer to include a hyperlink

Comment: Can you add in the relevant parts of the link into your answer? We ask this to help the OP out, so they will not have to search through information that may not pertain to them. This is also to preserve the relevant information in case the hosting site goes down. For more information, see this [meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259).

Comment: I know, I know. I keep asking you to do things. I swear we have reasons for it. If you have any questions, just let me know.